# mysqldump where clause producing no rows in output

Tags: mysql

My mysqldump statement is returning no actual data, just information about the table

Here is my statement:

```
mysqldump dbname tablename --where="date=SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)" > file.sql
```

If I omit the `--where` option I get all the results just fine, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the `--where`

EDIT: I got this working on a linux server; it didn't work on a Mac. Perhaps it is the way I have MySQL installed or something... If I figure it out I will post as an answer

Comment: What is the data type of the `date` column? Is it a full `DATETIME` or just a `DATE`?

Comment: If you execute `SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename WHERE date=SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)` do you get the expected result? I would expect you to, unless `date` has a time component.

Comment: Hi yes I do get the expected result

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess: Maybe you need to enclose `date` in back-ticks (`date` is a reserved word in MySQL):

```
--where="`date`=SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)"
```

Comment: Date is [not a reserved word.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)